# How to use openinviter with twitter and facebook?

Tags: contacts, import-contacts

I'm trying to use openinviter. It works well for yahoo, gmail, hotmail but I can't make it work for facebook and twitter. However, the openinviter website tells that facebook & twitter service are working. Is there something different to do when using facebook and twitter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a problem with Twitter, here's the fix:

http://jaidane.wordpress.com/2011/12/29/openinviter-twitter-plugin-unable-to-get-contacts-error-october-2011/